# How can I use str.title with another language?

Tags: python

I am using this code block:

```
>>> import re
>>> def titlecase(s):
...     return re.sub(r"[A-Za-z]+('[A-Za-z]+)?",
...                   lambda mo: mo.group(0)[0].upper() +
...                              mo.group(0)[1:].lower(),
...                   s)
...
>>> titlecase("they're bill's friends.")
"They're Bill's Friends."
```

It's from Python's documentation.

If the string includes a Turkish character like 'ö', string becomes

'BöRek'. What should I write in order to support all languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Unicode character properties database, by compiling your regex with `flags=re.UNICODE`:

```
def titlecase(s):
    return re.sub(re.compile(r"[\w]+('[\w]+)?", flags=re.UNICODE),
                  lambda mo: mo.group(0)[0].upper() +
                             mo.group(0)[1:].lower(),
                  s)
```

On Python 2, you'll need to use Unicode strings:

```
>>> print titlecase(u"börek")
Börek
```

Comment: Very good. Additionally, I don't want to capitalize some words like 've'. How can I add those words?

Comment: @Burak you can look at an exclusion dictionary in the substitution function: `lambda mo: mo.group(0) if mo.group(0) in excluded else ...`

Answer (score 1):

Use unicode strings, i.e. `titlecase(u'börek')`.